# Counter reset for numbering the figure

Tags: sectioning, counters

In my chapter, I have several sections.
How can I reset the counter of figures for each section?

i.e. In chapter 1, section 1, My figures should be numbered 1,2,3 (instead of 1.1, 1.2, 1.3).
In section 2, my figures numbering should restart and they should be numbered 1,2,3 as well (instead of 1.4, 1.5, 1.6).

Comment: Though certainly possible, this seems like a bad idea. How should one tell apart which figure 1 you do mean when you reference it?

Comment: In my chapter, the section constitutes of independent articles. Therefore, one can easily tell the difference between figures. I want this trick to only be applicable for only one chapter and not all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following. But as already mentioned in my comment, this seems like a bad idea to me. Are you really sure you want to do this?

```
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
```

To undo this effect you can use:

```
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
```

A complete example (which also shows the problematic behaviour of it):

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\begin{figure}% >>>
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%
  \caption
    {%
      duck1%
      \label{fig:duck1}%
    }%
\end{figure}% <<<

\section{Baz}
\begin{figure}% >>>
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%
  \caption
    {%
      duck2%
      \label{fig:duck2}%
    }%
\end{figure}% <<<
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Rouge because you only stated that you want that behaviour only in one chapter after I wrote my answer, see my edit for how to undo this effect.

Comment: Thanks @Skillmon, but it is not updating the figure number in the text. How shall that  be fixed?

Comment: @Rouge updating to what? Which figure number where? What should be updated in the text? I'm confused and don't understand what you mean at all.

Comment: oops sorry! It's working perfectly fine, I made a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Skillmon, is it possible to do the same trick for tables and equations? Which commands shall I use?

Comment: @Rouge the table counter is called `table` the equation counter is called `equation`, so just exchange the term `figure` in above's code with one of these.